# appropriate container to display images one by one

Tags: android, opengl-es, drawable

I am new in android development.  And I am building a location based app like google map(To some extent,we are reinventing the wheel :( ).

Like `maps.google.com`,the map data is generated as tiles in server and re-organized in the client. And in the html page,its easy to find the container to hold the tiles. For example,we can create some `img` element accordingly, and then put these `imgs` inside a `div` element.

Now in the android,which is the appropriate container to display the images?

In fact, I am reading the docs [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), and it seems that `ImageView` is the only way to display the `bitmaps`.  If this is true,then I have to create several  `ImageViewS` dynamically according to the `tile size` and the `size of the user screen`.  Also,according to the docs,`AsyncTask` should be used for performance enhancement. So each created `ImageView` will hold a `AsyncTask`,I am afraid which will out of my control.

So I wonder if there is any other solution can meet my requirement?

BTW,we use the `tiles` now,but we also have the plan to support the `vector` data which seems to have to use the `opengl`,so switch between different map types should be under consideration  .

---

**Update:**

If as `Raghunandan` suggested I should use the `ImageView`  to hold the satellite bitmaps in my app,but how about the `vector data` which should be still drawn use the opengl,then how to switch between these two types(views)?

Comment: Not necessarily a image view any other view with set background image will also work. And you can use one AsyncTask for updating all. I am not seeing any reason to panic.

Comment: use a UIL https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Your google maps problem is already very complicated for your current level of programming understanding. Please don't start piling on additional requirements to it now. In fact, you should be looking for ways to reduce the scope of your project, and not for ways to increase it. Stick to one problem for now and cut down the scope of your project drastically. That's the only hope you have that you can ever make some headway on this. For instance, focus on the tiles issue. Make it work for 4 tiles. 4 tiles, that's it. If you can't make it work for 4 tiles, break down the problem even further.

Comment: In any case, this problem is far too complicated for me. I'm just going to bow out of this discussion. Good luck with your project.

Comment: In fact, we have implement the tile image based feature,load the pre-created tiles served on the server, and we use the `ImageView` to hold the bitmap one by one.