# performance between ImageView or opengl-es when drawing multiple bitmaps in android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have multiple bitmaps to be drawn in the screen(the images will be loaded online and changed accordingly).

I can display them using either ImageView or opengl-es, so now I wonder if there is any performance difference between them?

Comment: Wow! That's a tough question. What are your requirements exactly? It entirely depends on your requirements, which seem to be super vague right now. And honestly, if you're just a beginner, I think you should stay away from OpenGL and just stick to ImageView for now (assuming it meets your requirements).

Comment: Also, I have no idea what you mean when you say "loaded online and changed accordingly"?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk:This is what I want to do .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713670/appropriate-container-to-display-images-one-by-one

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the link. OpenGL is indeed completely wrong for your use case. Do not even go down that path. Stick to the simpler View idea, be it an ImageView, or something like it, as referenced by the answers to your other question. Please delete this current question on performance whenever you can, it's just going to confuse other people who are looking for an answer to improve their OpenGL performance.

Comment: I have to draw to kinds of map datas:bitmaps and vector data. Then if I use the ImageView to display the image,and how about the vector data? I will switch between them. In fact, I just want to implement the similar effect like google map where the satellite layer is bitmap, and the Normal layer is based on vector data .

Comment: Your original question is the place to ask this last question. To avoid duplication, please don't ask it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same question a while back. I decided to use the ImageView widget, simply because I sought to avoid the complications of OpenGLES. The ImageView class is extremely fast, and later I would find out why: on my devices at least (Nexus 4 and Nexus 7), ImageView is implemented under the hood using OpenGLES. I found this out when my devices started streaming OpenGL rendering errors one day after a code change.

So in the end I had to wind up delving into OpenGLES and could not avoid it.